# redis-cli on windows 7 has strange ascii characters

Tags: redis

when I run my redis-cli on windows, it show the following message.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> help @generic
     [1mDEL[0m [90mkey [key ...][0m

    .......

       [1mDUMP[0m [90mkey[0m
       [33msummary:[0m Return a serialized version of the value stored at the fied key.
       [33msince:[0m 2.6.0

       [1mEXISTS[0m [90mkey[0m
       [33msummary:[0m Determine if a key exists
       [33msince:[0m 1.0.0
```

It seems that there is some ascii color charactars show not the color show in the window. Do I need to do some configuration in my windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those unix TTY color codes are not meant for cmd.exe on Windows, what you are seeing is a minor problem that is not addressed (yet).

Redis on Windows is beta software.
It makes sense that MSOpenTech focus on redis-server, and not on redis-cli which is mainly a testing client that technically isn't needed. On top of that, redis-cli works, it's only the default formatting of `HELP` and other feedback that's faulty.

You can work around this by using this redis-cli option:

```
--raw              Use raw formatting for replies (default when STDOUT is
                   not a tty).
```

To see all options, do:

```
redis-cli --help
```

If it bothers you, post an issue on (https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis) .

Hope this helps, TW